# How to detect user visited external website

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, cross-domain

External website A offers a form to be filled out only once. When a user has filled it out, the form will be hidden when he calls the website A again due to cookies.

Now I want to detect whether a user has been on website A. Basically, I think, I need to request website A "in the name of" this user and parse the response.

I tried using embedding, iframe, cross domain requesting, cross domain with proxy server. Either the browser restrictions block me or I can request the website, but with another session!

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the co-operation of the other website: it cannot. Browsers are designed to make that sort of invasion of privacy impossible.

If the other site is willing to expose that information, you could use Ajax via JSONP or CORS, or you could redirect to user to a URL on the other site which, in turn, redirects back to your site with a query string that indicates if the form has been filled out.